# Какой есть простой способ использовать последовательную нумерацию строк в базе mysql в двух столбцах одновременно?

Tags: php, mysql

Какой есть простой способ использовать последовательную нумерацию строк в базе mysql в двух столбцах одновременно?
Понятно, что в первом столбце мы используем autoincrement и mysql автоматически прописывает последовательную нумерацию строк.
Как использовать такую же функцию для другого столбца, который не должен зависеть от первого столбца (то есть простым copy->past не получится сделать), но у него должна быть тоже последовательность.
Даже если считывать из базы последний "индекс" и в скрипте прибавлять к нему "+1", то пока заполнется форма одним пользователем, другой пользователь может уже отправить заполненную форму и тогда вторая форма будет уже с ошибкой с записью в БД, так как такой "индекс" уже будет существовать. Есть вариант, при отправке формы, снова запрашивать последний индекс из базы, выполнять "+1" и пытаться записать в базу. Если такой индекс уже есть, то повторить запрос в базе и так далее, пока либо не будет найден свободный "индекс" либо пока не истечет таймаут обработчика.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360154/4804629

Comment: А для чего это требуется, каково практическое назначение ? Ведь в начале работы, пока автоинкремент не начал пропускать номера оба подхода дадут одинаковое число. Да, потом они конечно разойдутся и во второй колонке смогут появляться номера, которые до этого были, например если кто то перед вставкой записи удалил последнюю из таблицы.

Comment: Смысл в том, что есть некая форма, в которую пользователь вносит информацию и потом отправляет заполненную форму на сервер для сохранения в базе. При сохранении формы, пишется, скажем ID компании, в которую эта форма должна попасть и при этом, чтобы у каждой компании был свой последовательный порядковый номер, который не будет привязан к основному autoincrement, который ведет сама база. И весь смысл в том, что при просмотре или подсчете количества форм в каждой компании, чтобы были номера строго по порядку, не зависимо от того, сколько компаний вообще существует, для которых созданы формы.

Comment: Вот примерно, как примерно должна выглядеть таблица в базе: https://pastebin.com/A4pJhc2b